# vfp query like command not working

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-like, visual-foxpro

```
SELECT iif( LIKE(sol,'EM06%'), "other",sol) as solGroup;
    FROM dpgift GROUP BY solGroup
```

The above should give me a column containing unique sol values. In addition, any sol value starting with EM06 should be grouped into "other". It doesn't work though, instead it returns the following.

```
Solgroup
DM081
EM061
EM081
EM100
EM101
EM105
EM111
TM081
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong here? the 2nd and 3rd line should be called "other".

I've used this like command many times and it's never done this before. I can't see anything wrong with the syntax and I've tried other variations without success. I've even tried casting in case a certain field type doesn't work but the result is always the same.

edit: using a '*' and putting the wildcard string as the first parameter works. I've actually been making this mistake for a while in the following manner:

```
iif( (LIKE("4%",sol) OR sol = "4"),"8M","other");
```

The `like` does nothing here but i hadn't noticed since the '=' operator returns true if sol starts with '4' (can someone link me a reference to '=' behavior?). The reason i included the `sol = "4"` is because i assumed % meant one or more char rather than 0 or more.
Anyway, i've gone back and changed all my code to `iif(like("wtvr*",string),stringtrue,stringfalse)`

I imagine using '=' to compare strings is not recommended since it doesn't seem to be mentioned in the msdn library.

Comment: Maybe you have a char before `EM`, what happens if you do `iif( LIKE(sol,'%EM06%'), "other",sol)`

Comment: i tried that as well, didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another alternative is to use "$", AT() or ATC()

"$" means if the left side is found ANYWHERE in the right side...

iif( "EM06" $ sol, "other", sol )

AT() is to compare if a string is found in another, but IS CASE-SENSITIVE, returns the character position found in the string (VFP is 1-based, not zero-based)

iif( at( "EM06", sol ) > 0, "other", sol )

or

ATC() -- same as AT(), but is NOT case-sensitive.

If you specifically want the "EM06" to be at the start of the string, you could even just do a LEFT() comparison

iif( left( sol, 4 ) = "EM06", "other", sol )

or even

iif( ATC( "EM06", sol ) = 1, "other", sol )

and yes, these are all valid within SQL-Select..

Comment: left and atc both worked perfectly, thanks. Any idea why my like() didn't work?

Comment: @slicedtoad, LIKE() uses "*" as wildcard match, not "%"

Comment: oh, order is also important. wildcards must go in the first parameter.